# Python Regex to match OpenWindow.document.write( [this] )

Tags: python, regex

I've got a webpage which contains document.write javascript commands. These command are structured like:

```
OpenWindow.document.write("text that I want")
```

I would like to use a regular expression to return either a list or a match object of all [text that I want]. Could someone please help me?

Sample code so far:

```
f = open("filename",'r')
allhtml = f.read()
results = re.findall(the_regex,allhtml)

for s in results:
    Do Stuff
```

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to reconstruct the page which is created by a series of OpenWindow.document.write javascript calls, where OpenWindow is a window other than the one from which the html came.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
import re

html = '...... your html page .... '
textlist = re.findall(r'OpenWindow\.document\.write\(([^\)]*)\)', html)

print "".join(textlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try a regex like this:

```
OpenWindow\.document\.write\s*\(\s*"((?:[^"\\]+|\\.)*)"\s*\)
```

If it's always a simple double quoted string.

It works with escapes, and matches things like:

```
OpenWindow.document.write("foo(\"bar\") baz('')")
```

Note that it's not fool proof: JS comments, quotes, regex, other HTML are just a few things that could give you invalid results.

Comment: I saw this one second, otherwise I'd have accepted it. The JS was computer-generated, so it had no complications.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [69]: s
Out[69]: 'OpenWindow.document.write("text that I want")'

In [70]: r=re.findall(r'"(.*)"',s)

In [71]: r
Out[71]: ['text that I want']
```

or do something similar to this:

```
for line in my_html:
    if "OpenWindow.document.write" in line:
        r=re.search(r'"(.*)"',s)
        print r.group()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the text which I want isn't actually in square brackets, I will fix the question.

Comment: Thanks, but that will still return the text inside any brackets, not just those preceded by OpenWindow.document.write, which is what I was really going for.